# Automatically Generating Daily Posts For A Blog With Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently I have a rake task which I will run daily with the Heroku Scheduler.

It currently will generate a new post for the user every day when the rake task is executed as long as today's date is after the "start date" of the users account.

This is the code for the rake task:

```
namespace :abc do 
desc "Used to generate a new daily log"

task :create_post => :environment do

User.find_each do |currentUser|
 starting_date = currentUser.start_date

 Post.create!(content: "RAKED", user: currentUser, status: "new") if Date.today >= starting_date && Date.today.on_weekday?
end

puts "It worked yo"     
end

end
```

My problem is if someone makes an account then sets their start date sometime in the past (so they can fill in old posts) my current rake task will not generate the backdated daily posts. Does anyone have any ideas about how to resolve this so that the rake task still performs its current job but also deals with this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
namespace :abc do
  desc "Used to generate a new daily log"
  task :create_post => :environment do
    User.find_each do |currentUser
      starting_date = currentUser.start_date
      if Date.today >= starting_date && Date.today.on_weekday?
        if currentUser.posts.count.zero?
          starting_date.upto(Date.today) { |date| currentUser.generate_post if date.on_weekday? }
        else
          currentUser.generate_post
        end
      end
    end
    puts "It actually worked yo!"
  end
end
```

In User model,

```
def generate_post
  posts.create!(content: "RAKED", status: "new")
end
```

Your logic remains the same, I just loopes over the starting date to the current date to create backdated posts. Checking post count to zero will ensure that the condition is true only for the new user/user whose posts are not created earlier.

Hope it helps..

Comment: Thanks, this is a great answer!

Comment: I m glad it helped..i would suggest you to change the topic/question to be more general. Like the error you faced for backdating, or similar..the question is not actually 'how to automatically generate daily posts' but different.

Comment: Hi, just a followup: I tried implementing this & I get the following error: NoMethodError: undefined method `upto'

Comment: Just an update: I had to use "starting_date = currentUser.start_date.to_datetime" instead of the above code